# How to join two objects in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I want to filter two objects in datasets array  by label with date . I use in react-chartjs-2. I don't know how do i filter.

Example :

```
First Object : {
    "id": 2,
    "customer_id": 4,
    "date": "2019-05-15T21:00:00.000Z",
    "wbc": 15,
    "vitamin": 14
}
Second Object : {
    "id": 3,
    "customer_id": 4,
    "date": "2022-05-22T21:00:00.000Z",
    "wbc": 20,
    "vitamin": 5
}
```

I need to this :

```
datasets: [
      {
        label: "WBC",
        data: [
          { x: "2019-05-15", y: 15 },
          { x: "2022-05-22", y: 20 },
        ],
        backgroundColor: "#003f5c",
        pointRadius: 8,
        pointHoverRadius: 8,
      },
      {
        label: "Vitamin",
        data: [
          { x: "2019-05-15", y: 14 },
          { x: "2022-05-22", y: 5 },
        ],
        backgroundColor: "#ffa600",
        pointRadius: 8,
        pointHoverRadius: 8,
      },
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

1. Place the items in an array so they are more easily managed;
2. Create an array with the keys you need in your datasets: (*wbc*,*vitamin*,etc...) and custom settings for each key ( *bg-color*, etc... );
3. Reduce the keys array to a datasets array containing objects with the shape you expect:

```js
const items = [{
    id: 2,
    customer_id: 4,
    date: '2019-05-15T21:00:00.000Z',
    wbc: 15,
    vitamin: 14,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    customer_id: 4,
    date: '2022-05-22T21:00:00.000Z',
    wbc: 20,
    vitamin: 5,
  },
];

const keys = [{
    type: 'wbc',
    settings: {
      backgroundColor: '#003f5c',
      pointRadius: 8,
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
    },
  },
  {
    type: 'vitamin',
    settings: {
      backgroundColor: '#ffa600',
      pointRadius: 8,
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
    },
  },
];

const datasets = keys.reduce((a, k) => {
  const o = {
    label: k.type.toUpperCase(),
    data: items.map((i) => ({
      x: new Date(i.date).toLocaleDateString(),
      y: i[k.type],
    })),
    ...k.settings,
  };
  a.push(o);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(datasets);
```